# android -security issues and protecting data and url

Tags: android

I'm about to export my app . 
I've some concerns about security ,i've worked about 3 month on this app and I want to protect the data . 
I've database about 17mb data and I used sqlcipher to encode it , I heard that it's possible someone get the password of the db , is it right ? if so , How can I prevent this ? is there any way to encode this password too ?

the other issue is about urls, some parts of my application is connecting to internet and get's data from a webserver . 
is it possible anyone could find out this url ? I don't want anyone find this url .
if so , How to prevent this ??

thanks you

Comment: There is not much you can do. You can hide the things a little but a dedicated attacker will always find it out.

Comment: if I don't put the password in the app and get it later from the internet , where can I store it ? somewhere private that no one can read it ?